# group by hour and post (multiple)

Tags: php, laravel

I want something like this:
[Table](https://ibb.co/k0syKTd)

And my database table is like this:
[Database](https://ibb.co/R3rwMcG)

How can I get this records group by (hour and post) at the same time?

And How can I print this results on html?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT post_id, hour, COUNT(*) FROM <table_name> GROUP BY post_id, hour`

Comment: @Áron-pop-adorjánn thanks bro

Comment: do you know how can I print this on html?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp